# CMake finds non-existent Python after uninstalling Anaconda

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, cmake, anaconda

When running CMake (version 3.0.2 on Ubuntu 15.10), it is unable to find my python2.7 installation. Instead, CMake finds a non-existent Python installation `/home/username/anaconda2/bin/python2.7`:

```
-- Could NOT find PythonInterp: Found unsuitable version "1.4", but required is at least "2.7" (found /home/username/anaconda2/bin/python2.7)
-- Could NOT find PythonInterp: Found unsuitable version "1.4", but required is at least "2.6" (found )
...
--   Python 2:
--     Interpreter:                 NO
--     Libraries:                   NO
--     numpy:                       /home/username/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver )
--     packages path:               lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

I recently uninstalled Anaconda by means of deleting the `~/anaconda2`, deleting relevant lines from my `.bashrc`, and deleting the Anaconda backup of my `.bashrc`.

I can "fix" the problem by providing explicit `-D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python` but I'm more concerned that the Anaconda Python is still hanging around (or rather that cmake still thinks it is) and I don't have the expertise to be sure that there aren't any other problems in the CMake report.

The things I have already tried/checked:

- `which python` returns `/usr/bin/python -> /usr/bin/python2 -> /usr/bin/python2.7`
- `echo $PATH` has no mention of conda, and `( set -o posix ; set ) | grep conda` returns nothing
- Running `python` starts the correct (non-Anaconda) shell
- Providing explicit `-D` options to cmake does override its penchant for the non-existent, though I haven't yet tried overriding numpy
- `python3` is found fine by default, which makes sense since it was unaffected by Anaconda
- `hash -r` had no effect
- Restarted bash, started a bash shell without `.bashrc`, and rebooted the computer more than once
- Reinstalled cmake

I can't tell if this is a problem with the way I uninstalled Anaconda (deleting the directory is the [official](http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install) method), or with some weird caching thing like hash. Or something else entirely.

Comment: Use system python instead

Comment: Am I not using system python? I'm trying to use system python, I think.

Comment: I see. You want to only reference system python my mistake.

Comment: did you check all this in an existing build directory? deleting the cmake cache is not in the list of things you have tried...